# Would a jQuery popup to check user age prevent page being crawled by bots?

Tags: jquery, bots

I am working on a site that requires a jQuery popup to check that the user is over 18 before they can view the page content.  Would this popup prevent bots from crawling the page?

Comment: That depends completely on the point you load content. If you only do it *after* the age check, then yes it will.

Comment: Further information: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43594/age-verification-in-website

Comment: Ok, so if I load the page content and then load the popup it will be fine then.  Thanks